# How to assign a dynamic range of bits

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Assume I have three registers concatenated like so:

```
{C, A, Q}
```

Where C is one bit, and A and Q are, say, 8 bits.

I need to periodically perform a shift operation like so:

```
if (shift_regs) {C, A, Q} <= {C, A, Q} >> 1;
```

Another register, P, starts with a value equal to the number of bits in Q, in this case 8, and counts down by one every time a shift occurs. The whole sequence stops when P reaches 0, and the output result is 16 bits equal to `{A, Q}`.

However, I want perform an optimization by detecting the case where Q prematurely becomes zero before all its bits are shifted out, and assign the output result to `{{8-bits_shifted_so_far{1'b0}}, A, Q[7:8-bits_shifted_so_far]}` instead.

Example sequence:

```
C = 0, A = 8'b1101_0100, Q = 8'b0000_0011
```

1) after first shift, `{C, A, Q}` becomes `{1'b0, 8'b0110_1010, 8'b0000_0001}`.

2) after second shift, `{C, A, Q}` becomes `{1'b0, 8'b0011_0101, 8'b0000_0000}`.

3) Q is now zero, so assign output to `{{8-bits_shifted_so_far{1'b0}}, A, Q[7:8-bits_shifted_so_far]}`, i.e. `{6'b00_0000, 8'b0011_0101, 2'b00}`.

How can I implement this in verilog or systemverilog?

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. Does your output need to hold the value `{{8-bits_shifted_so_far{1'b0}}, A, Q[7:8-bits_shifted_so_far]}` until the next point at which Q is zero? Or is your output reset to something else whenever `Q != 0`?

Comment: Sorry, this is actually an exercise for a sequential binary multiplier, but I've tried to simplify the scenario in hopes that my question can be understood. The output needs to hold the value `{{8-bits_shifted_so_far{1'b0}}, A, Q[7:8-bits_shifted_so_far]}` only if the remainder bits in Q (that have not been shifted out yet) have a zero value. Otherwise, it should keep shifting until all bits in `Q` are shifted out.

Comment: there is no such thing in verilog as a dynamic range. So, you cannot do it. The only possibility is to build your output vector bit by bit in a loop with a bunch of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with your example, I will assume the output has a width of 16 bits.

Your problem can be simplified, since you are performing this operation at the point when `Q == 8'h00`, then your output does not need to contain `Q[7:8-bits_shifted_so_far]`, it can be replaced with zeros. As Serge pointed out, dynamic ranges are not possible in verilog, but your problem has a simple solution:

```
//Note the blocking assignment
if(shift_regs) {C, A, Q} = {C, A, Q} >> 1; 
//Set the output to A bit-shifted left by the desired amount
if(!Q) output = {8'h00, A} << (8-bits_shifted_so_far);
```

Essentially, all you are doing is outputting `A` bit shifted relative to how many shift operations have been performed.

Comment: How can I express `bits_shifted_so_far` in verilog?